# Spring integration - poller for inbound adapter is not closing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to use spring integration to sftp a few files from different directories to my local dir.

Now i can grab the 3 files i need fine but the application never ends, it seems to get stuck constantly in a transaction loop. I think i need to shut down the poller although this is a guess. Any ideas where i am going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration ttp://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">
  <bean id="sftpDownloader" class="SftpDownloader" p:SftpChannel-ref="SftpChannel" p:SftpChannel1-ref="SftpChannel1" p:SftpChannel2-ref="SftpChannel2"/>
  <int:channel id="SftpChannel">
    <int:queue/>
  </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="SftpChannel1">
    <int:queue/>
  </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="SftpChannel2">
    <int:queue/>
  </int:channel>
  <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${sftp.user}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}"/>
    <property name="privateKey" value="${sftp.privateKey}"/>
    <property name="proxy" ref="httpProxy"/>
  </bean>
  <!---->
  <bean id="httpProxy" class=" com.jcraft.jsch.ProxySOCKS4">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${proxyHost}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${proxyPort}"/>
  </bean>
  <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdaptor" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" local-directory="${local.dir}" auto-create-local-directory="true" auto-startup="false" channel="SftpChannel" remote-directory="${remote.dir}" filename-pattern="file1" delete-remote-files="false" charset="UTF-8" remote-file-separator="/" local-filename-generator-expression="#this">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="30000"/>
  </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
  <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="1SftpInboundAdaptor" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" local-directory="${local.dir}" auto-create-local-directory="true" auto-startup="false" channel="SftpChannel1" remote-directory="${1.remote.dir}" filename-pattern="file2" delete-remote-files="false" charset="UTF-8" remote-file-separator="/" local-filename-generator-expression="#this">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="30000"/>
  </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
  <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="2SftpInboundAdaptor" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" local-directory="${2.local.dir}" auto-create-local-directory="true" auto-startup="false" channel="SftpChannel2" remote-directory="${2.remote.dir}" filename-pattern="file3" delete-remote-files="false" charset="UTF-8" remote-file-separator="/" local-filename-generator-expression="#this">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="30000"/>
  </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
  <bean id="fileNameGenerator" class="org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultFileNameGenerator"/>
</beans>
```

The below snippet sftps 2 different files from the same remote dir. This is where it gets stuck in the loop after getting either file

```
private static void sftpFiles(String party) throws Exception {
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter 1Adapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) applicationContext
            .getBean("1SftpInboundAdaptor");
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter 2Adapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) applicationContext
            .getBean("2SftpInboundAdaptor");
    if (party.equals(Constants.1)) {
        1Adapter.start();
    } else if (party.equals(Constants.2)){
        2Adapter.start();
    }
    SftpDownloader sftpProcessor = (SftpDownloader) applicationContext.getBean("sftpDownloader");
    boolean fileDownloaded = sftpProcessor.receiveFile(party, "");
    LOGGER.info((fileDownloaded ? "Successful" : "Failed") + " downloading file);
    applicationContext.stop();
}
```

This snippet works fine (sftps 1 file, different remote dir, and ends successfully)

```
private static void sftpFile(String party) throws Exception {
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) applicationContext.getBean("sftpInboundAdaptor");
    adapter.start();
    SftpDownloader sftpProcessor = (SftpDownloader) applicationContext.getBean("sftpDownloader");
    boolean fileDownloaded = sftpProcessor.receiveFile(party, "");
    LOGGER.info((fileDownloaded ? "Successful" : "Failed") + " downloading);
}
```

The sftpdownloader class just checks to see the size of the message to tell the job whether it failed (if file is size 0)

As i said, it works in that it downloads each file but when it tries to do the 1/2 it gets stuck with the below constantly looping.

> Error DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,686 [jmsContainer-4]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,687 [jmsContainer-2]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,687
>   [jmsContainer-7]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,719 [jmsContainer-7]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,719
>   [jmsContainer-4]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,719
>   [jmsContainer-2]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,839
>   [jmsContainer-9]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,839 [jmsContainer-6]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,839
>   [jmsContainer-5]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,839 [jmsContainer-1]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,845
>   [jmsContainer-1]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,845
>   [jmsContainer-5]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,846
>   [jmsContainer-9]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:10,846
>   [jmsContainer-6]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,161
>   [jmsContainer-3]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,161 [jmsContainer-8]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,161
>   [jmsContainer-10]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,169 [jmsContainer-8]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,169
>   [jmsContainer-3]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,169
>   [jmsContainer-10]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,721
>   [jmsContainer-7]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,721 [jmsContainer-4]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,721
>   [jmsContainer-2]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,726 [jmsContainer-7]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,726
>   [jmsContainer-2]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,727
>   [jmsContainer-4]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,847
>   [jmsContainer-1]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,848 [jmsContainer-5]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,848
>   [jmsContainer-9]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,848 [jmsContainer-6]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,863
>   [jmsContainer-9]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,864
>   [jmsContainer-6]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,864
>   [jmsContainer-1]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,864
>   [jmsContainer-5]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,918
>   [EES Idle Connection Monitor Thread]   [[]]
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing
>   expired connections DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,918 [EES Idle Connection
>   Monitor Thread]   [[]] org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute
>   - Closing expired connections DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,918 [EES Idle Connection Monitor Thread]   [[]]
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing
>   connections idle longer than 5 SECONDS DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:11,918
>   [EES Idle Connection Monitor Thread]   [[]]
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections
>   idle longer than 5 SECONDS DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:12,171
>   [jmsContainer-8]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:12,171 [jmsContainer-10]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Initiating transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:12,171
>   [jmsContainer-3]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating
>   transaction commit DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:12,177 [jmsContainer-8]
>   [[]] org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager -
>   Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:12,177
>   [jmsContainer-10]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT DEBUG 2017-07-12T06:51:12,177
>   [jmsContainer-3]   [[]]
>   org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Creating
>   new transaction with name [jmsContainer]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT

These are ran as 3 separate jobs, so my bashscript will pick up which job to run which in turn determines the file I need to receive. So I’m getting the files for all 3 jobs, but the jobs looking for either file 2 or 3 will hit the above loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since it is unclear what you are asking I vote to close your question. The loop you show is just `DEBUG` for the consistent transactions from the JMS listener container, which you should agree fully unrelated to the SFTP. Also you don't show the code of your `SftpDownloader`. You should really come up with as simple as possible description and only with the scope of the problem. Since JMS isn't mentioned in your question, I don't know how to help you...

Comment: I didn't add SftpDownloader because it only validates the size of the incoming message, it doesn't do anything else. It lets spring handle the sftp. My issue i think is that after receiving the message it either keeps polling or something else takes over and gets trapped in the snippet of debug message i gave. That's all i get from my logs so it's hard to know where the problem lies. Simply put my sftp doesn't work for the 2 files within the same dir whereas it works for the 1 file in a different dir. For the 2 files it grabs them and gets stuck in the snippet it showed.